# Request.Query is always empty

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I'm working on updating an old ASP .NET MVC project to .NET Core 6. In the old project, I was accessing the request parameter "BATRequestID" through the `Request` object.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AffectedHardwareAdd()
{
    int? batID = int.Parse(Request["BATRequestID"]);
}
```

From what I have gathered online, the equivalent line in .NET Core 6 would be

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AffectedHardwareAdd()
{
    int? batID = int.Parse(Request.Query["BATRequestID"].ToString());
}
```

but everytime the `Query` parameter is empty. I have also tried adding `IHttpContextAccessor` to my controller (with `builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` added in `Program.cs`) but the `Query` on the request parameter is also empty.

I know I can reformat the post method to take the ID directly, but this syntax is used throughout the program and I would not like to have to change most of my backend if possible.

I've checked to make sure the request is the same in both the old and new project, so I believe it is something on the back end side, such as something missing in services or `app.run`

Comment: Your code looks OK. What do you have in the `Request.QueryString`? How do you call your endpoint?

Comment: add query params to the method signature, to have those params in query do the following ```public ActionResult AffectedHardwareAdd(int BATRequestID)``` this will guarantee that will get this param as a query param. to check this you can make a call to this endpoint like this ``` POST /api/CONTROLLER_NAME?BATRequestID=2```

Comment: You should bind these values to a controller model for various reasons... you can then delete all these direct calls to the request.

Comment: @LukaszSzczygielek, the QueryString is also empty. The URL I use is the normal MVC format, ../controller/action/params, so for this action it is "/ControlPanel/AffectedHardwareAdd"

Comment: @odaiwa I have tested this and this does work, but it still doesn't answer my question as to why the Request.Query is empty

Comment: In ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core MVC, you should pretty much never directly interact with the Request or Response objects in the controller. If you need to get data into your action method, then use parameters on the action method, which can be bound to the query string, route, or body.

Comment: @JarrettMitchener, and your url is like "/ControlPanel/AffectedHardwareAdd?BATRequestID=abc"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the routing method of `/controller/action/params`, then you put the passed value in `Request.RouteValues["id"]`:
[image]

[image]

The Key value of `RouteValues` is the parameter name of the default route you set in `Program.cs`:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

If you want to use `Request.Query` to get parameters, then you need to pass the parameters as a QueryString, ie `/controller/action?paramName=xxx`:
[image]

[image]

For more detail, you can refer to this document: [URL matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#url-matching).